# Taking a string and modifying it with an integer

Tags: java

Being fairly new to Java, I have an exercise where the user will be asked to enter a word. Next, they will be asked to enter a number. Then the program will modify the word by taking the number and implementing it to change the string. For example, if the word "Hello" was entered, and the integer entered was the number "3", it will take each character in the string (Hello) and move them each 3 letters down in the alphabet, which would then make the output word "Khoor". I recently learned about method replacing (.replace) in the same chapter as this question but it seems like having to clarify every single letter with a replace would be too lengthy. This is what I have so far.

```
public class Lab03Exercise7 {
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        //  Prompt user to enter a string
        System.out.print("Enter a word");

        //  Import Java scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

        int numberinput;

        String wordinput = input.nextLine();

        //  Prompt user to enter an integer
        System.out.print( "Enter a number");

        numberinput = input.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/ + char is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
        String wordInput = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        int numberInput = input.nextInt();

        StringBuilder updatedStr = new StringBuilder();
        for (char c : wordInput.toCharArray()) {
            updatedStr.append((char) (c + numberInput));
        }
        System.out.println("Updated string: " + updatedStr);
    }
}
```

**Explanation:** Break the word into an array of characters and iterate through the array. During iteration, add the number to the character and append the updated character to a `StringBuilder` object. Note that you can add an integer to a `char` value but you need to cast it before appending to the `StringBuilder` object.

Comment: Note that your code have the same problem as mine, for example z with shift greater then 1 will be convert to a non-alpha-betic character

Comment: @maio290 - added the explanation. Note that I didn't duplicate the already existing answer. I saw another similar answer when I refreshed the page after answering it. Nevertheless, my answer is still valuable for newbies because it uses two things different from the other answer: (1) it uses the enhanced loop (2) it uses `toCharArray`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = 0 ; i < wordinput.length(); i++) {
        final char currentChar = wordinput.charAt(i);
        sb.append((char)(currentChar + numberinput));
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

So basically, we're going character by character and adding the shift that you've got from the user. here I don't handle the edge cases - where we need to rotate after `z` / `Z`

In general, this algorithm called `Caesar Cipher` and you can get some more info about it here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/caesar-cipher-in-cryptography/

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that

Answer (score 2):

As highlighted by @maio290' comment you have to use the ascii table to solve your problem, differentiating between lowercase characters and uppercase characters. Starting from the assumption we have a 26 chars alphabet (a-z and A-Z) in the example we are translating the chars of three positions so we will have for example:

- "Hello" will be translated to "Khoor"
- "zed" will be translated to "chg"

In the case of z char it will be translated to c, I'm posting an example explaining the situation:

```
public class Caesar {

    public static String encode(String original, int k) {
        char[] arr = original.toCharArray();

        StringBuilder encoded = new StringBuilder();
        for (char ch : arr) {
            char initialCharacter = Character.isLowerCase(ch) ? 'a' : 'A';
            int dec = ((int)(ch - initialCharacter) + k) % 26;
            encoded.append((char)(dec + initialCharacter));
        }
        return encoded.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(encode("Hello", 3)); //<-- will print Khoor
        System.out.println(encode("zed", 3)); //<-- will print chg
    }

}
```

You have to transform your char to int and after retransform it to char , differentiating between lowercase chars and uppercase chars and assuming an alphabet of 26 chars , for further details see the ascii table.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is gonna help to solve your problem. Just do not forget to handle it after 122(letter z). You can check the ASCII table here (https://theasciicode.com.ar/)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      String word = "word";
      char[] arr = word.toCharArray();
      int count=0;
      for (char c : arr) {
          //!!Handle if the sum is bigger than 122 (letter z), you need to do some easy math.
          arr[count] = (char) (((int)c) + 3);
          count++;
      }
      String newWord = new String(arr);
}
```